# Chern Character Number Belongs to integer

Tags: kt.k-theory-and-homology, characteristic-classes, chern-classes

From `Getzler's definition` [1], we know the odd Chern character is the following map 
$$Ch:K^1(M)\to H^{odd}(M;\mathbb C),~g\mapsto \sum_{k\geqslant0}(-\frac1{2\pi\sqrt{-1}})^k\frac{k!}{(2k+1)!}Tr[(g^{-1}dg)^{2k+1}],$$
where $M$ is a closed manifold and $g$ is an element in the homotopy class of $[M,GL_N(\mathbb C)]$.

I have some question in my mind, but I am not sure whether it is solved or not.

**Q**:

- Is there an answer(conjecture)to say the odd Chern character number $<Ch(g),[M]>$ is an integer?

  In other words, for the even Chern character $ch:K(M\times S^1)\to H^{even}(M\times S^1,\mathbb C)$, is $<ch(\xi),[M\times S^1]>$ an integer, for any $\xi\in K(M\times S^1)$?
- Or there exists a counter-example?

*PS*: It is welcome to introduce the background of such a problem.

[1] *Ezra Getzler*, MR 1231957 [**The odd Chern character in cyclic homology and spectral flow**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0040-9383(93)90002-D), *Topology* **32** (1993), no. 3, 489--507.

Comment: There is no essential difference between the even and odd chern character. See http://mathoverflow.net/questions/233228/characteristic-classes-for-odd-k-theory/239295#239295

Answer (score 1):

Here is one example, I think it is right. 
$M:=\mathbb P^2\times S^1$, then $M\times S^1\cong \mathbb P^2\times \mathbb T^2$.

So, we can find the line bundle $\mathcal O(1)$ on $\mathbb P^2$ and $L$ on $\mathbb T^2$, with $c_1(L)=1$. Hence the pull-back vector bundle $pr^*_1\mathcal O(1)\oplus pr^*_2L$, where $pr_i$ denotes the canonical projection on the $i$th component of $M\times S^1$.

Thus, $<ch(pr^*_1\mathcal O(1)\oplus pr^*_2L),[M\times S^1]>=\frac12$.

I hope, it is right. Please let us check together.